# knockout js `create callback` used with mapping plugin when model's mapping written as a function

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RobertSudwarts/en784ojo/40/) which is doing exactly what I want so far ie  listing a bunch of contacts (using the mapping plugin) and extending each 'contact' with an additional observable `isEnabled` which is used to control the (enabled/disabled) status of the input boxes displayed in each row.

What I'm having trouble understanding, however, is how to code the `contactsMapping` as a function. Where I currently have:

```
var contactsMapping = {
    'contacts': {
        key: function (item) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.id);
        },
        create: function(options) {
           return new contactModel(options.data);
        }
    },
};
```

I want to use a function (for cleaner access to `this` etc as described variously):

```
var contactsMapping = function() {
    var self = this;

    // self.contacts = [what goes here??] 
};
```

`contacts` in this model is (educated guess) somehow transcribed by the mapping plugin as an observable array but, how do I inject the `key` and `create` functions correctly?

Thanks for any help/pointers...

Comment: What version of knockout are you using? I have tried this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gonefishern/3pt270k9/3/) and it works with ko 3.2.  Your fiddle is using ko 2.0.0 and wanted to make sure that is correct as what I have does not work on ko 2.0.0 for some reason.

Comment: @nathan I've updated the reference/link in my question to the fiddle -- now using v.3.2 -- the model etc still works as originally intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping functions accept a third parameter which is the object the mapped values are injected into (is extended to).  So if you wanted to extend to `self`, pass it in.

```
var contactsMapping = function (data) {
    var mappingOptions = {
        'contacts': {
            key: function (item) {
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.id);
            },
            create: function(options) {
                return new contactModel(options.data);
            }
        },
    };
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions, this);
};
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/en784ojo/41/)